# Converting .csv file to text file using Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

Would like to ask if how to convert a .csv file generated from macro to .txt file?

I have this Excel macro that gathers data from the website and create a table and output it to a .csv file, but for some reason I wasn't able to copy its contents to an existing .csv file as it returned special characters instead of the correct output.

Please help me, with the program I am currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A csv file is a text file. U can just change the extension like this

```
Name "C:\\**\\a.csv" As "C:\\**\\a.txt"
```

Comment: it got corrupted when i save as txt file like this one.

Comment: K     ! Û1(òl  Ä   [Content_Types].xml ¢(

Comment: Please share the code. Seems like you are dumping binary data and not text