# VBA to open .csv file with notepad save as .txt

Tags: excel, vba, csv, txt

I need to create a macro that will open a .csv file, but open it in notepad (this preserves the formatting that I require) then save this open notepad as a .txt file.

My current code will open the .csv file in notepad as required. But I cannot save is as a .txt file with the same FileName.

Any suggestions?

```
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    FileName = "file1"
    FilePath = "C:\folder_structure\"
    
    'This opens the .csv file in notepad and works
    Shell "notepad.exe " & FilePath & FileName & ".csv", vbNormalFocus
    
    '***** The comments below contain the approaches I have tried but none work *****
    
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & FileName & ".txt.", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows
    'Application.SaveAs fileName:=FilePath & fileName & ".txt.", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows
    'ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=FilePath & fileName & ".txt.", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows

    
    'in essense I want this
    open notepad .SaveAs FilePath & FileName & ".txt"
```

Comment: Gotta ask, why not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753883/converting-csv-file-to-text-file-using-excel-macro)?

Comment: Side notes: `ActiveWorkbook` refers to an Excel workbook, `Application` refers to the host program for this code, and `ActiveDocument` refers to a Word document. Clearly none of those are Notepad.

Comment: @BigBen The answer you posted as a suggestion does work but it also just overrites the original .csv. I need to keep the soucre .csv file

Also, I appreciate the clarification on the prefix code names

Comment: Maybe use [`FileCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filecopy-statement) first?

Comment: @BigBen Actually, this might just work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `FileCopy`:

```
FileCopy FilePath & FileName & ".csv", FilePath & FileName & ".txt"
```